# Не работает проверка массива на повторяющиеся слова

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

Задание -- найти повторяющиеся слова в массиве и вывести их. Решил реализовать вот так:

```
for i:=1 to 30 do
  for i1:=1 to 30 do
    if w[i1]=w[i] then
    begin
      write(w[i],' ');
      break;
    end;
```

Но выводится полностью исходный массив, без каких либо изменений. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что для любого номера элемента в коде будет момент, когда и i, и i1 равны ему, причём одновременно. Ну и сработает if w[i1]=w[i] (чего бы элементу не быть равным самому себе?) - вот тебе и вывод всех элементов.

Нужно исключить такое "пересечение". А заодно исключить две проверки каждой пары (в прямом и обратном порядках). Лучше всего так:

```
for i:=1 to 29 do
  for i1:=1+i to 30 do
```